# MongoDB Extended JSON support in Athena(Presto)

Tags: mongodb, amazon-athena, presto, mongodb-atlas

I am using mongodb atlas to export data to s3 using following aggregation pipeline:

```
pipeline: [
    {
       $match: { ...
        }
    },
    {
        "$out": {
            "s3": {
                "bucket": "name",
                "region": "ap-south-1",
                "filename": "name",
                "format": {
                    "name": "json.gz"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Above code outputs json in below [MongoDB Extended JSON](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) format as described [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/data-federation/supported-unsupported/pipeline/out/#std-label-adf-out-stage-limitations) :

```
      "key": {
            "$numberDouble": "410.0"
        },
```

Notice "$numberDouble" which raises error in athena (presto), since it is not a standard json, it gives following error:

> Current token (START_OBJECT) not numeric, can not use numeric value
> accessors